# Proper way for sending and receiving all bytes from a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, c++11

I am developing a client and a server application that send and receive messages between each other. The code is portable and designed for running on Windows, OSX and Linux.

However when the client runs on Windows, I am experiencing the problem of random socket disconnects. This is not happening on Mac or Linux. I am still trying to figure out which part of the server or client app causes this issue and I am suspecting the code I am receiving and sending the data.

Can you please take a look at my code for sending and receiving data if it is correct?

Sending data:

```
int _sendmsg(int socketfd, std::vector<char>message)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    size_t bytesleft = message.size(); // how many we have left to send
    int n;
    while (total < message.size()){
        n = send(socketfd, message.data() + total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n < 0){
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("----> throw EXCEPTION _sendmsg  returned -1”));
        }
        total+=n;
        bytesleft-=n;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Receiving data (for simplicity in the code I have set a fixed value in bytes_needed_payload = 30000. In my app this number is calculated from the first 4 bytes of the message) :

```
int _recieve(int socketfd, std::vector<char> * charbuffer)
{
    size_t bytes_needed_payload = 30000;
    charbuffer->resize(bytes_needed_payload);
    size_t bytes_cnt_payload = 0;

    while(bytes_cnt_payload < bytes_needed_payload)
    {
        int bytes_rcv_payload = recv(socketfd,charbuffer->data() + bytes_cnt_payload,bytes_needed_payload - bytes_cnt_payload, 0);

        if (bytes_rcv_payload == 0){
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " <<
                       "####  int _recieve: recv return 0 bytes. [second while loop]. Returning from function." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (bytes_rcv_payload == -1){
            std::cout << "int _recieve(int socketfd, std::vector<char> * charbuffer)) - returned -1" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        bytes_cnt_payload += bytes_rcv_payload;
    }

    return bytes_cnt_payload;
}
```

EDIT 1: Here is my complete _recieve code:

```
int clientserver::_recieve(int socketfd, std::vector<char> * charbuffer)
{
    //-----------
    //first part: receive total bytes of data expected from the
    //from the first 4 bytes of the charbuffer
    size_t bytes_needed = 4;
    char len_bytes[4];
    memset(len_bytes,0,bytes_needed);
    size_t bytes_cnt=0;

    while(bytes_cnt < bytes_needed)
    {
        int bytes_rcv = recv(socketfd, &len_bytes[bytes_cnt],bytes_needed - bytes_cnt, 0);

        if (bytes_rcv == 0){
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " <<
                       "####  int recieve: recv return 0 bytes. [first while loop]. Returning from function." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (bytes_rcv == -1){
            displayErrno("int clientserver::recieve(int socketfd, std::vector<char> * charbuffer) - first while loop");
            return -1;
        }

        bytes_cnt += bytes_rcv;
    }

    if (bytes_needed != bytes_cnt){
        std::cout << "----> EXCEPTION IN recieve func (payload length). Bytes recieved not equal to bytes expected. Expected: " << bytes_needed << " recieved: " << bytes_cnt << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("----> EXCEPTION IN recieve func (payload length). Bytes recieved not equal to bytes expected."));
    }

    //-----------

    //second part: receiving the payload
    size_t bytes_needed_payload = bytesToInt(len_bytes,4);
    charbuffer->resize(bytes_needed_payload);
    size_t bytes_cnt_payload = 0;

    while(bytes_cnt_payload < bytes_needed_payload)
    {
        int bytes_rcv_payload = recv(socketfd,charbuffer->data() + bytes_cnt_payload,bytes_needed_payload - bytes_cnt_payload, 0);

        if (bytes_rcv_payload == 0){
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " <<
                       "####  int recieve: recv return 0 bytes. [second while loop]. Returning from function." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (bytes_rcv_payload == -1){
            displayErrno("int clientserver::recieve(int socketfd, std::vector<char> * charbuffer)) - second while loop");
            return -1;
        }

        bytes_cnt_payload += bytes_rcv_payload;
    }

    if (bytes_cnt_payload != bytes_needed_payload){
        std::cout << "----> EXCEPTION IN recieve func (payload). Bytes recieved not equal to bytes expected. Expected: " << bytes_needed_payload << " recieved: " << bytes_cnt_payload << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("----> EXCEPTION IN recieve func (payload). Bytes recieved not equal to bytes expected."));
    }

    return bytes_cnt_payload + bytes_cnt;
}
```

Comment: Your send looks OK (though there are some tweaks you can make to it), but please show your real receive code, not code you altered.

Comment: @blitz: that is what he should be doing. -1 is error, 0 on receive is disconnect (send does not return 0), and >0 is success.

Comment: [OT]: you may pass `message` by const ref in `_sendmsg` (and by ref in `_recieve`)

Comment: @billz send returns -1 if there is an error. Can it return zero when bytes_needed_payload > 0?

Comment: @Yiannis Mpourkelis: Please provide some more information about what happens. Does any of the error messages in the above code show up? Does the error occur on the client or on the server side?

Comment: @StefanK. I will try to debug now and post my findings. It might take me some time because the disconect problem appears after 10min or 30min or 2 hours.

Comment: Yiannis Mpourkelis: Is this a real network connection (e.g. TCP/IP) or do you use other kinds of connections (Sockets, Pipes, ...) for the communication? Between different machines or just on the same machine? Have you tried multiple Windows Machines? It might also be an issue caused by a special installation (e.g. driver issues) or a hardware issue (bad memory)?

Comment: @StefanK. It is TCP/IP and I am using blocking sockets. The server app is running on Ubuntu Linux x64. The clients on Windows or Mac. Only the Windows client has the problem. I tried it on other windows machines also and I get the same problematic behavior.

Comment: Is data continually being sent between the machines, or is it sporadic?

Comment: @James. Data is sent continually between client and server. The data sent is between 10bytes and 350KB. The data flow is like this: Client_1 sent image data to server > server receives and forwards image data to Client_2 > Client_2 receives image data and requests next image data from server > server forwards request to Client_1 > Client_1 receive request and sends image data to server and so on...

Comment: @RemyLebeau. OK, bellow the EDIT 1 is the complete code of the _recieve function

Comment: @Yiannis Mpourkelis: Is the TCP connection between the nodes kept open or is it closed after each transmission? If it is kept open, the problem might be caused by some socket option like SO_KEEPALIVE, which seems to be active on windows per default (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923586/windows-tcp-socket-has-so-keepalive-enabled-by-default). Also investigate others like SO_TIMEOUT ...

Comment: @StefanK. The connection remains always open. I've read this article and looks like it is not my case because I am always sending data between client and server.

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis: I know its not your case, just about SO_KEEPALIVE being activated per default on Windows. Try to set all relevant socket options in http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt (SO_KEEPALIVE, SO_SNDBUF, SO_RCVBUF, SO_RCVLOWAT, SO_RCVTIMEO, SO_SNDLOWAT, SO_SNDTIMEO) manually and compare between Linux/Windows/Mac again if it still has different behaviour. Alternatively check via getsockopt() if all machines have the same defaults and which differ.

Comment: PS: Try to write a routine that periodically sends some small dummy packages (i.e. "a ping packet with length == 0") every 20 seconds to keep the connection alive. If this helps you can try to increase the interval and find the real limit.